Does the User ID change in TeamViewer when the IP is changed?
Is there still the possibility of any access to a PC with TeamViewer and all its variants of this access (Uncontrolled through an account or without an account with a Permanent password, etc.) if the IP and provider have changed?. Or is a new ID or password given when changing the IP and provider, or all together?.

The user ID is tied to a keypair stored within the Registry; it never changes regardless of the IP address.
